# While using an ntfs smb share for mac users, do symbolic links and extended attributes work?

Tags: windows-server-2008, mac, ntfs, symbolic-link, attributes

We have a majority of mac users but we'd rather support their file sharing using a Windows server with an ntfs drive, or at least a Linux server with ext3. We've had trouble, much trouble, utilizing the OS X server software and after the years are now looking to abandon it. What's mostly holding us back is the fact that the mac users very often utilize symbolic links and other special features that exist for an HFS+ partition.

The shared locations are mostly *primary* storage and not just used as an archive storage location. While there is an option to create symbolic links under ntfs, I'm curious if there is anything I need to look out for if I were to move the files over to a new partition that's hosted from a Windows server from the HFS+ partition; in addition, how well creating a symbolic link from a mac might work. I am also worried about windows backup software and if it will ruin these special sym links, and how placing permissions on sub-folders will work. Alternatively I could remotely backup the files using a mac and Bru, nonetheless I still want to get away from mac server for hosting the shares.